# Spring Integration: Routing messages by percentage of messages received

Tags: spring-integration

How would I implement a requirement to split an existing Spring Integration based request channel to route a fixed percentage of messages to a Rabbit MQ based channel? Routing is NOT to be based on payload or header. Is there an out of the box way to specify that one out of so may should go on one channel and remaining on the other? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way...

```
<bean id="counter" class="java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger" />

<int:router id="percentageRouter" input-channel="routePercentage" 
        expression="@counter.getAndIncrement() % 10 == 0">
    <int:mapping value="true" channel="tenpercent" />
    <int:mapping value="false" channel="ninetypercent" />
</int:router>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the prompt insight, Gary!

Comment: If the answer solves your problem, please mark it as accepted to help others searching for a similar solution.